# How to change drupal commerce status message?

Tags: commerce

I have created a custom cart and checkout. When product is added to cart, drupal displays a message "The product XYZ has been added to your cart" through rules which links to default cart. How can I change the message to link to my custom cart? 
Note: I checked the other questions but none is related to changing links to carts or DC etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah Okay, I got an idea, If I change the path mysite/cart to link to my new cart address? Is this the correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the rule called 'Display an Add to Cart message' and edit it.

You'll see there is a related action in there called 'Display a translatable Add to Cart message'.  In mine, I've even added a **second** action that takes folks to my cart immediately after adding an item:

[image]

In any case, what I would do is delete that specific action and then Add a new action instead.  From the '**System**' section, choose '**Show a message on the site**'.

[image]

Then, in the 'Value' field of that action, you can add whatever message you want and you can add html in it as well.  So you can add something like:

```
Ready to <a href="/your_custom_cart_url">checkout</a>?
```

Let us know if this worked for you...

Comment: Thank you Boriana for your reply. I had already tried this but how I will change it because after I click edit, it just displays Data selector and nothing where I can change the link

Comment: Check my updated response.  Does that work your you?